# Problemas com calculo de "ARVORE DA VIDA"

Tags: c, lógica

Boa tarde, estou com um problema preciso fazer o seguinte:

Crie um programa, em linguagem C, que calcule o tamanho da árvore da vida,
após um determinado número de ciclos de crescimento, levando-se em consideração que a
árvore começa com um metro de tamanho.

Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 1 ciclo, fica com 2 metros.

Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 2 ciclos, fica com 3 metros.

Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 3 ciclos, fica com 6 metros.

Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 4 ciclos, fica com 7 metros.

Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 5 ciclos, fica com 14 metros.

Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 6 ciclos, fica com 15 metros.

Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 7 ciclos, fica com 30 metros.

até agora eu fiz o seguinte

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void funcao_01() // sub programa
{
    int ciclos;
    printf(" \n\n             --   ARVORE DA VIDA   --  \n\n");// cabecalho
    printf("  Digite o valor de ciclos desejados: ");
    scanf("%d",&ciclos); // le valor digitado pelo usuario

    float resultado;
    if (ciclos % 2 == 1)
    {
        resultado = (ciclos * ciclos);
        --resultado;
    }
    else
    {
        if(ciclos % 2 == 0)
        {
            resultado = ciclos * 2;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n  Voce escolheu %d, ciclos\n\n  Sendo assim voce tem %f metros.\n\n\n\n",ciclos, resultado);
}

int main() // programa principal
{
    funcao_01(); // chama funcao
    return 0;
}
```

pois a relação que eu tinha criado era a seguinte:

"Quando o ciclo é impar ele dobra.. quando é par ele soma +1"

no começo ate deu certo mas dai quando começa com números maiores não tem mais logica isso, então eu gostaria de "padronizar" digamos assim, mas a minha pergunta mesmo é, qual o método mais fácil para chegar a resolução deste problema?

Answer (score 7):

**Vamos lá:**

> Crie um programa, em linguagem C, que calcule o tamanho da árvore da
> vida, após um determinado número de ciclos de crescimento

*Como o enunciado falou vamos criar um programa que calcule o tamanho da árvore da vida, então já temos um nome pro nosso programa:*

```
void calculaArvoreDaVida() {
  //
}
```

---

> Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 1 ciclo, fica com 2 metros.
>
> Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 2 ciclos, fica com 3 metros.
>
> Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 3 ciclos, fica com 6 metros.
>
> Uma árvore, com 1 metro de tamanho, após 4 ciclos, fica com 7 metros.
>
> "Quando o ciclo é impar ele dobra.. quando é par ele soma +1"

*A lógica está correta só o algoritmo que não:*

```
// usamos um loop for para percorrer a quantidade de ciclos
for(int i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++) {
    
    // verificamos se i é impar ou par 
    if (i % 2 == 1) {
        // se for impar multiplicamos o resultado por 2
        resultado = resultado * 2;
    } else {
        // se for par somamos + 1
        resultado = resultado + 1;
    }
}
```

---

**Por fim:**

> levando-se em consideração que a árvore começa com um metro de tamanho.

*Não esquecer de inicializar a variável `resultado`:*

```
int resultado = 1;
```

---

***Ps.:*** Verifique o código, pois não testei em `C`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void calculaArvoreDaVida() // sub programa
{
    int ciclos;
    printf(" \n\n             --   ARVORE DA VIDA   --  \n\n");// cabecalho
    printf("  Digite o valor de ciclos desejados: ");
    scanf("%d",&ciclos); // le valor digitado pelo usuario

    int resultado = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i <= ciclos; i++) {        
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            resultado = resultado * 2;
        } else {
            resultado = resultado + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n  Voce escolheu %d, ciclos\n\n  Sendo assim voce tem %f metros.\n\n\n\n",ciclos, resultado);
}

int main() // programa principal
{
    calculaArvoreDaVida(); // chama funcao
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: para '1' e '2' da certo! ja para 3 em diante da tudo diferente, e outra tem que trocar o valor de resultador de FLOAT para INT, mas enfim, ja em 3 fica em 8 Mts, 4 fica em 5 Mts, 7 fica em 128Mts

Comment: Verdade, o `if` tem que verificar o índice `i` e não os ciclos. Já arrumei, é que fiz o codigo em `Swift` e confundi na hora de postar aqui 

Comment: Pois bem, tem outro porém, alem de dar um erro 'C99' na linha do for

Comment: @AGenaro Aceite essa resposta aqui, que está correta. O erro de C99 que você recebeu é porque está usando um compilador configurado para um padrão antigo de C, chamado C89, que não aceita declarar variáveis direto no for (`for (int i = 1 ...`). Sua pergunta não faz exigências de a resposta ser em C89, então essa resposta aqui é a correta.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVIDO:

pois bem consegui resolver o problema vou colocar o código aqui para quem quiser ver a resolução.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void calculaArvoreDaVida() // sub programa
{
    int ciclos;
    int resultado = 1;
    int x;
    do
    {
        // cabecalho
        printf(" \n\n             --   ARVORE DA VIDA   --  \n\n");
        printf(" Digite 0 (zero) para sair do programa\n\n");
        printf("  Digite o valor de ciclos desejados: ");
        scanf("%d",&ciclos); // le valor digitado pelo usuario
        if (ciclos == 0) // se o usuario digitar zero em tela imprime mensagem
        {
            printf("\n\n         BYE BYE !  \n\n"); // mensagem exibida caso valor digitado for zero
            return;
        }
        for(x = 1; x <= ciclos; x++ ) // teste e implementacao
        {
            if (x % 2 == 1)
            {
                resultado = resultado * 2;
            }
            else
            {
                resultado = resultado + 1;
            }
        }
        //mostra mensagem na tela caso sucesso
        printf("\n\n  Voce escolheu %d, ciclos\n\n  Sendo assim voce tem %d metros.\n\n\n\n",ciclos, resultado);
        // volta variavel resultado para 1 para refazer o ciclo sem nenhuma variavel atribuida.
        // pois se nao tiver ele vai pegar valores anteriores e manipular apartir daqueles
        // sendo assim nao da certo.
        resultado = 1;
    }
    while(ciclos != 0);
}
// PROGRAMA PRINCIPAL
int main() 
{
    calculaArvoreDaVida(); // chama funcao
    return 0;
}
```